# Centos :: Can't remove / delete package

Tags: centos, php, yum

On my server I'm running PHP 5.5.1. I would like to install `php-gd`, but when I'm trying to install it, it always says:

```
yum install php-gd
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.supportex.net
 * epel: mirror.1000mbps.com
 * extras: mirrors.supportex.net
 * updates: mirrors.supportex.net
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.3.3-23.el6_4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4 for package: php-gd-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-gd-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4
           Installed: php-common-5.5.1-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-test)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.1-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

it seems that the php-gd package is available on the server for php 5.3. I can't delete or removed it from the server. I'll always receive this message: Package(s) php-gd available, but not installed.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You installed PHP from the `remi-test` repository. It is disabled by default. You should re-enable this repository if you want to install further PHP packages from it.

Comment: Alright, I enabled it, but now I'm receiving the following error: http://pastie.org/private/3i0ocu8lqqwfzssrxeui0w. It takes the wrong version, php 5.4 and not for 5.5.

Comment: I said `remi-test`, not `remi`.

Comment: Sorry, changed it and now everything works fine! Thanks!